# Best way to use Spartacus built-in Events to capture data into GTM?

Tags: google-tag-manager, spartacus-storefront

I’m using the TagManagementFeatureModule in version 3.2.2. I was wondering if there is a recommended/documented OOTB way to use Spartacus events (CartAddEntrySuccessEvent, CartRemoveEntrySuccessEvent, CartUpdateEntrySuccessEvent) for GTM.

I don’t think I see that the dataLayer pushed entry contains the event key, which is used by GTM triggers. Same case for the NavigationEvent, is there an OOTB way to use it to capture Page Views?

Edit: Currently I created my own module and extending the GtmCollectorService, where I implement the `map` function to add this event key based on `event.constructor.name`, but I was assuming there was a default way to do it with the GtmModule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right, there is no OOTB way to do this. The reason is simple - it all depends on the TMS solution being used, and on the specific clients needs.

That being said, your approach to override the `GtmCollectorService` and implement `map` is correct. However, instead of `event.constructor.name` I suggest to use the static `type` property that's present on each of the event classes.

Comment: I'll use `(event.constructor as typeof CxEvent).type;` then, thank you.

Comment: Though I would argue over the non-use of the `event` property, for GTM specifically. Given that GTM uses this key for triggers, I would expect the `feature-libs/tracking/tms/gtm/services/gtm-collector.service.ts` to have a basic map implementation where it maps the value. This still can be overriden, it just provides more functionality OOTB and it's only to GTM.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. We will look into it. Do you mind creating a ticket on our GH, and posting a link?
Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Of course, thank you. https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/12423